# OnPreferenceChangeListener for every setting

Tags: android, android-preferences

I know that I can do something like this:

```
Preference pref = findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_vibrate_on_key));
pref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                Object newValue) {
            LogUtil.d("Working!");
            return true;
        }

});
```

But I would like to add a Listener to every preference.
I tried doing:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
sp.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(new OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
            LogUtil.d("working!");

        }

});
```

but it doesn't work.
Is this possible? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542938/sharedpreferences-onsharedpreferencechangelistener-not-being-called-consistently) is what you were doing wrong - right ?

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you want the same listener called each time, this might be a simpler solution:

```
Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener changeListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        // Code goes here            
        return true;
    }
};

EditTextPreference pref = (EditTextPreference)findPreference(getString(R.string.pref1));
pref1.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(changeListener);

EditTextPreference pref2 = (EditTextPreference)findPreference(getString(R.string.pref2));
pref2.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(changeListener);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that `onSharedPrefererenceChanged` is fired upon saving the preference (when you click BACK or HOME in `PreferenceActivity`). I think that the easiest way is to create single class implementing `OnPreferenceChangeListener` and switch through `Preference.getKey();` and set it as `OnPreferenceChangeListener` for each Preference.

Comment: `onSharedPreferenceChanged` wont get called on BACK/HOME. (or even leaving the activity)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Listening describes this approach. @YoushaAleayoub are you shure that listener is still registered after launchig PreferenceActivity and that it is registered to same SharedPreferences?