# How to edit SharedPreferences so that OnSharedPreferenceChanged is called

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a `PreferenceScreen` in which I have a `CheckBox Preference` and a simple `Preference`, which calls a custom dialog. In this custom dialog the user can pick a number. By pressing OK in this dialog I want to save the number by editing my `sharedPreferences`. After saving it should call automaticaly the `OnSharedPreferenceChanged` method.

The CheckBox Preference works fine.

Comment: I wonder if you have tried 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799038/onsharedpreferencechanged-not-fired-if-change-occurs-in-separate-activity

Comment: I dont understand what you want to show me here...
I am registering and unregistering the onchangelistener and it works, I know it because it works with the CheckBox Preference.
After picking the number in the dialog I want to save the number in the SharedPreferences and saving a number should automaticaly call the OnSharedPreferenceChanged method. I dont know if this is even possible...

Answer (score 2):

Your custom dialog should extend DialogPreference.  If the preference has been modified call persistXXX() (XXX being the name of the type) like in this example:

```
@Override
public void onDialogClosed(final boolean positiveResult) {
    if( positiveResult && this.isPersistent() ) {
        final StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        b.append(this.hour).append(':');
        if( this.minute < 10 )
            b.append('0');
        b.append(this.minute);
        this.persistString(b.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try it in the next days and report