# Shared Preference returns always the default value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Here is code I am Using to create and store value in Preference.
outgoing is String variable.

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(outgoing, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();                
editor.putString("PhoneNo","Hi");
editor.commit();
```

Here is the code to get value from SharedPreference.

```
SharedPreferences sp 
=getSharedPreferences(outgoing,Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
String calln = sp.getString("PhoneNo","0");
Toast.makeText(mContext, "SHARED"+calln,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: where do you call this code? is it in the same activity or a different one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should probably call the `getSharedPreferences` on the context from which you are accessing them.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Therefore, depending on how you can access your context, if you pass it to some other activity or in an asynchronous task, here are some examples of usage:

```
this.getSharedPreferences(outgoing, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

context.getSharedPreferences(outgoing, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(outgoing, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Also, one way you can test your stuff is to use a listener when `SharedPreferences` get changed:

```
onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)

Called when a shared preference is changed, added, or removed.
```

[here is how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3799894/3928341)

You can also use the `Preference Manager` to obtain the `SharedPreferences`:

```
PreferenceManager.getSharedPreferences(YOUR_CONTEXT).getString(
                    "PhoneNo", "0");
```

Or to store them:

```
PreferenceManager.getSharedPreferences(YOUR_CONTEXT).edit().putString(
                    "PhoneNo", "Hi").commit();
```

Answer (score 2):

The most likely reason that Shared Preference always returns the default value is that you saved the value in one preference file and then tried to retrieve it in another preference file. This can happen if you do call `getPreferences()` from different Activities, because `getPreferences()` creates a different preference file based on the activity it is created in.

#### Solution

The easiest solution is to always get your shared preferences like this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

This will use a single preference file for the entire app.

#### Alternate solution

If for some reason you need to use different preference files, then you can do

```
final static String PREF_FILE_1 = "pref_file_1";
...
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_1, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Just make sure you always use the right file name for the preferences you are trying to save and retrieve.

#### Local preferences

If you really only need a preference for a specific Activity, then you can use `getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)`. Just don't expect to be able to retrieve the values from another Activity in the same way.

#### See also

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32016912/3681880) describes the differences between the various ways of obtaining `SharedPreferences`.
- [Difference between getDefaultSharedPreferences and getSharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946135/difference-between-getdefaultsharedpreferences-and-getsharedpreferences)
- [Mess with the shared preferences of android - which function to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37953002/mess-with-the-shared-preferences-of-android-which-function-to-use)

Answer (score 1):

change this `Activity.MODE_PRIVATE` to this `Activity.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS`, issue is probably due to different context during storing value and accessing value.

Comment: Thanks For Reply. I have changed it to Activity.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS. But it still give me DEFAULT VALUE.

Comment: "**This constant was deprecated in API level 23.** `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` does not work reliably in some versions of Android, and furthermore does not provide any mechanism for reconciling concurrent modifications across processes. Applications should not attempt to use it. Instead, they should use an explicit cross-process data management approach such as ContentProvider."

Answer (score 1):

When putting values, try changing this:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(outgoing, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to this:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(outgoing, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Same when getting values - don't forget to add `getApplicationContext()` in your call to `SharedPreferences`

EDIT:
Check that your "outgoing" String is the exact same in both Activities

Comment: Thanks For Reply. I have add getApplicationContext but there is no difference in result It still Give me DEFAULT VALUE.

Comment: Are you calling the retrieving method (getString) from the same Activity?

Comment: No from Different Activity.

Comment: And are you sure you are using the exact String value of "outgoing"? Have you declared it in both Activities?
Try replacing outgoing with a hardcodded String (as "test" or something) when calling SP in both Activities, and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Oh.. Get it. There is some problem with outgoing. It's working with "test". Thanks for the help. I make changes it will done. :)

Comment: Glad to hear! See my edited answer, and if it has helped please accept it. 10X and Happy Coding!

Comment: Can you help me to store sharedprference file in particular location.? When I am trying to do same it gives me Error that File Contains Path separator.

Comment: Ya It is possible. I am trying but get some error. There is some small mistakes that I can't get.

Comment: Please PM me so I can try help you