# onPreferenceChanged not called if SharedPreference stringset changed

Tags: android

**In my code I do**

```
String name = ...
SharedPreferences prefs = ...

Set<String> servers; // = new HashSet<String> ();
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit ();
servers = prefs.getStringSet ("serverlist", new HashSet<String> ());
servers.add (name);

edit.putStringSet ("serverlist", servers);
edit.apply ();
```

**The registered listener looks like this**

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged (SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)
{
    if (key.equals ("serverlist"))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

On changes to preference the listener is never called. Only if i remove the preference, commit/apply it (required) and store it again the listener gets called:

```
edit.remove ("serverlist");
edit.apply ();
edit.putStringSet ("serverlist", servers);
edit.apply ();
```

Changes on simple properties (String, Boolean, ...) are properly signalled to the listener.

Am I doing something wrong?
Or - is that a known issue?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799038/onsharedpreferencechanged-not-fired-if-change-occurs-in-separate-activity and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener

Comment: same happens to me. It has nothing to do with weak reference.
I have the same listener, it gets called when the key references anything except a stringset

Comment: The links above don't help. They did not address the StringSet property.

The only solution (workaround) i found so far is to delete the shared preference, apply the changes and set the (previously saved) values to the preference again.
This fires the call to onPreferenceChanged afterwards.