# How to use OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a Activity that has variable number and a (InputMethodService) Service class that gets a number from the activity.

What I want is that when I change variable number in activity, that reflects on service class.

So I wrote the code like this, but It didn't work. Is there a mistake or wrong code?

```
class Activity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        var customNumber: Int = 100

        val myPreference = getSharedPreference("number", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        myPreference.edit().putInt("changeNumber", customNumber).apply()
    }
}
```

in Service ( get number from activity )

```
class myService : InputMethodService(), SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    var changedNumber: Int = 0

    override fun onSharedPreferenceChanged(sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences?, key: String?) {
    changedNumber = sharedPrefrences!!.getInt("changeNumber", 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're forgetting to register/unregister the listener:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3799894/7434090

Comment: Thanks, but I have more question, I'd like to get number in a service ( inputmethodservice ), not in a activity. Service component have no onPause(), onResume() method. Then how to register/unregister the listner?   Can onStartInputView(), onDestroy() do it?

Comment: I would think `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` would be best.