# Deprecated Preference Activity method

Tags: android, android-preferences

I am working with `PreferenceActivity` but when I call my preference xml(prefs.xml) with the help of `addPreferencesFromResource()` it says this method is deprecated and "This function is not relevant for a modern fragment-based PreferenceActivity". Is there any alternative of this method? How can I handle this?

```
package com.adi.preferencedemotest;

public class PrefsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") <-------
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs); <-------
    }

}
```

Note: may be my question rates as a duplicated but I didn't find any.

Answer (score 4):

There aren't any documented alternatives that I know of. The method was deprecated in API 11 and from that API onwards you would create a class extending `PrefrencesFragment` and call the `addPreferencesFromResource()` method in the `onCreate(`) there.  Obviously that wouldn't work for on devices supporting API 10 and below.

Here is the answer I got my information from:
[What to use instead of "addPreferencesFromResource" in a PreferenceActivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822319/what-to-use-instead-of-addpreferencesfromresource-in-a-preferenceactivity/6822461#6822461)