# addPreferencesFromResource deprecated - any other solution?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I'm trying to create a preferences page to save user preferences.

Currently I am sat with this in preferences.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="User Preferences">
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:title="Save Credentials"
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:summary="Save User Login Details"
            android:key="credentialsPref" />
        </PreferenceCategory>                

</PreferenceScreen>
```

And this in PreferencesActivity.class:

```
public class PreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.preferences);
    }

}
```

That all works ok but it states that addPreferencesFromResource is deprecated, is there a better way of doing this - I have seen use of PreferenceFragment but it looks like an incredibly long winded way of going about this task, unless I'm mistaken?

(New to Java and programming in general)

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822319/what-to-use-instead-of-addpreferencesfromresource-in-a-preferenceactivity