# How to use preferencesResId instead addPreferencesFromResource

Tags: android

I just start to study android, so have some problem

i have a file res/xml/settings.xml - settings from menu
create class Prefs and try to use settings from file above

```
package org.example.sudoku;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity {
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
       }
    }
```

Problem, that addPreferencesFromResource cant be used and i need to use preferencesResId (according to comments), but if i write something like this

```
     preferencesResId(R.xml.settings);
```

its not good.

Where is error in code? Could any1 help?
Also i try to learn android by using book - Hello Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`preferencesResId()` is not a method, it is a placeholder in conversation for your resource id (`R.xml.settings`).

So although

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
```

Is deprecated, if you're using this approach, this is still the most correct way - there isn't another way using the deprecated approach.

I suggest you look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822319/what-to-use-instead-of-addpreferencesfromresource-in-a-preferenceactivity) SO question - it tells you what you *should* be using instead (PreferenceFragments). If you need a code sample, fire up Eclipse and the ADT plugin and make a `SettingsActivity` via the `new Activity` Wizard.

And as usual, here is the full JavaDoc for [`PreferenceActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html).

Comment: many thanks for fast reply... need to reed a little bit more information and try

Comment: @Bki Welcome to SO! And, exactly, trying is everything :-) If you haven't done so already, I also suggest reading the [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) tutorials as well as the [Android](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) tutorials. Then if you're stuck and it's a good question, make a new question on SO - we like to answer [good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions).

Comment: i reread all writed code and in additional recomended by you link - as result - i catch idea, found errors and fix it - now its ok. Many thanks for your help . also this http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/28673.aspx was usefull too