# Stuck with @SuppressLint("NewApi") (developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity)

Tags: android

I'm a begginer with Android and currently stuck with the lession: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

In the part **Create the Second Activity**, when I try to use the code:

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I get the error below:

**@SuppressLint("NewApi")** -> The attribute value is undefined for the annotation type SuppressLint.

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.**HONEYCOMB**) -> HONEYCOMB cannot be resolved or is not a field.

**getActionBar**().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); -> The method getActionBar() is undefined for the type DisplayMessageActivity.

**NavUtils**.navigateUpFromSameTask(this); -> NavUtils cannot be resolved

Someone let me know how to solve?
Here is what I imported:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
```

Many thanks!

Comment: What android API code is your app targetting.

Comment: Oh, i see, it was 8. i just set it to 15 now, and there are two issues remaining:

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this)

Thanks for your help, i'm still update my sdk.

Comment: @Lạng Hoàng If you found a solution please post it as your answer.

Comment: Hello all, thanks for all of you.

I just have tried again with ADT that download from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download, import something new follow eclipse's hint and everything is ok now.

Full import list bellow:
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Build;

Anyway, the problems is sloved at this time, thanks for all of you again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your build target is NOT set to API Level 14 or higher. This is not a bug, please close this issue.

**(In eclipse: Project => Properties => Android)**

Answer (score 24):

[`SuppressLint`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/annotation/SuppressLint.html) annotation was added in API level 16. You need to either:

- set your build SDK to 16 or higher, or
- copy `tools/support/annotations.jar` from your Android SDK to the project `libs`.

Comment: is targetsdk must be 16? that's what you mean?

Comment: @MiguelRivera Build sdk, the one you compile with. Defined in project.properties for Eclipse/ADT based tooling.

Comment: @MiguelRivera After setting `target=android-16` (or higher), clean and rebuild.

Answer (score 22):

> import android.annotation.SuppressLint;

Comment: hallo, is this an addtional lib, i get this "The import android.annotation cannot be resolved" when try to import.

Answer (score 11):

I ran into the exact same problem. CTRL-SHIFT-o (organize imports) filled in the missing import for me.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, it solved all my errors. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Move your cursor over "SuppressLint", which will be underlined in red. Select the fix option "Fix project setup". From the popup list select "add archive 'annotations.jar'. Have a happy day.

Answer (score 2):

It works, if you set the line `@SuppressLint("NewApi")`
above the class declaration! (In  [this lesson](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html), this line is positioned within `onCreate`, and that doesn't work!)

Answer (score 2):

ctrl+shift+O to import libraries and ctrl+s to save made the error go away for me.