# supressLint cannot be resolved to a type error (android beginner tutorial online)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-lint

In thefollowing Code, I get a problem when following the **Android beginners** tutorial at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#StartActivity

Eclipse is saying: supressLint cannot be resolved to a type error with a small x next to that line `@SuppressLint("NewApi")`.

I cannot save and run the application.

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: See this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16758835/1225669

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stuck with @SuppressLint("NewApi") (developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643657/stuck-with-suppresslintnewapi-developer-android-com-training-basics-firsta)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding @SuppressLint("NewApi") annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601601/understanding-suppresslintnewapi-annotation)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
```

Comment: If an answer has helped you, it's always good to use the upvote button. ;-)

Comment: Thanku ! You save my day :)

Comment: Cheers @Shubham1164 . It's always nice to receive an appreciative comment, but some people don't like that as it can clog up the comments list. So the usual protocol is to click the upvote arrow (located above the number **2**, above).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you need to organize your imports.  This is frequently a cause for the "cannot resolve to a type" error.  You haven't imported the code package which contains the definition of SuppressLint, so the compiler doesn't know what it means yet.

In Eclipse, a quick way to organize imports is Ctrl+Shift+O on Windows or Cmd+Shift+O on Mac.  This automatically checks for packages you need and adds them to your import statements.

To use @SuppressLint you will want to make sure that you have the android.annotation.SuppressLint package.

Answer (score 0):

I think this helps you because supresslint annotation was added in API level 16

- set your build SDK to 16 or higher
- Copy tools/support/annotations.jar from your Android SDK to the project

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

While the OP's question is for Eclipse, I faced similar issue on Android Studio and the issue was because of the "CSV plugin"

Uninstalling this plugin, resolved the issue for me.
(Might be useful for those who're having similar scenario and are landing on this question because of this plugin issue)