# Ensure no data loss when service is destroyed

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm building an application and need to ensure my data is retained if the service gets destroyed. I've used preferences to save the user's settings, which works fine.

The data I now want to store are longitudinal and latitudinal values set when the application is first configured, which are being used as a base location and are vital they retain their value.

I'm assuming content providers are overkill for my needs.

*Anyone dealing with the problem caused by the change to fragmented preferences, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822319/what-to-use-instead-of-addpreferencesfromresource-in-a-preferenceactivity) is worth a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your activity onCreate()/onResume() load the sharedPref data. and inside  onDestroy()/onPause() of your activity save the service data