# Alternative to addPreferencesFromResource as its deprecated

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, splash-screen

I create Preference activity on my app to allow user to start/stop background splash screen music as follow :

```
public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity{

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);    
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);


    }    
}
```

and inside xml folder create prefs.xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
    <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <CheckBoxPreference 
         android:title="splash music" 
         android:defaultValue="true" 
         android:key="checkbox" 
         android:summary="Plese remove music "/>
    </PreferenceScreen>
```

and this code for splash activity :

```
 public class Splash extends Activity{  
    MediaPlayer ourSong;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle Drandroid) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(Drandroid);
         setContentView(R.layout.splash);  

    ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.splashsound); 

     SharedPreferences getPrefs = 
               PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    boolean music = getPrefs.getBoolean("checkbox", true);
    if (music == true)      
    ourSong.start();

    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(5000); }
              catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace(); }
              finally{
    Intent openTurkeyTrip = new Intent("com.android.dr.MENU");

        startActivity(openplanet); }}                                   
                                };
         timer.start();   }

@Override
protected void onPause() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    ourSong.release();
    finish();
          } 
       }
```

how can i solve it with other class which is not deprecated also my app will support old and new devices as below  :

```
  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

any advice will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What to use instead of "addPreferencesFromResource" in a PreferenceActivity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822319/what-to-use-instead-of-addpreferencesfromresource-in-a-preferenceactivity)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`PreferenceActivity` is not deprecated.

`addPreferencesFromResource()` on `PreferenceActivity` *is* deprecated. However, if you are supporting API Level 10 or lower, you have no choice but to use it, at least on those devices.

The non-deprecated approach is to use `PreferenceFragment` in conjunction with `PreferenceActivity`, as is described in [the `PrefereceActivity` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html). If your app is only supporting API Level 11 and higher, just use that. If your app is supporting older devices, either:

- Use `addPreferencesFromResource()` all the time, as it still works, until you drop support for the older versions, or
- Use `addPreferencesFromResource()` only on the older devices (by checking `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`), and rely on the new fragment-based system on newer devices

Comment: my app will support both old and new devices ( post edited) , how to get it work for both as you mention : Use addPreferencesFromResource() only on the older devices (by checking Build.VERSION.SDK_INT), and rely on the new fragment-based system on newer devices in code , please , thanks

Comment: @AndroidStack: That goes a bit beyond what can reasonably be covered in a StackOverflow answer. Here are some sample projects that demonstrate the results: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Prefs/FragmentsBC https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Prefs/SingleHeader https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Prefs/SingleHeader2 That being said, unless you are a fairly experienced Android developer, I would recommend that you just use `addPreferencesFromResource()` until you drop support for older devices.

Comment: would you please my dear sir check this post , thanks .:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16379420/preferencefragment-java-lang-runtimeexception

Comment: The link given above has also been deprecated in API 29, for androidX see the documantion of Preference Activity here : https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/package-summary