# Add preferences deprecated

Tags: android, android-preferences

I just noticed that `addPreferencesFromResource();` is deprecated in `Android` now. I tried looking for what I should use now and the developers site still has it this way. Does anyone know what I should use instead?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822319/what-to-use-instead-of-addpreferencesfromresource-in-a-preferenceactivity

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16374492/alternative-to-addpreferencesfromresource-as-its-deprecated

Answer (score 1):

As I pointed out in my comment, just use a [Preference fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html)

Answer (score 1):

PreferenceActivity is still fine, but you have to use a PreferenceFragment subclass to do it now.  It looks something like this:

```
public class SetupActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
    }

    public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
    {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getActivity(), R.xml.preferences, false);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }
    }
```

You then store the preferences in `preferences.xml` like this:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <EditTextPreference
    android:key="rest_server"
    android:defaultValue="@string/default_rest_server"
    android:summary="@string/rest_url_desc"
    android:title="@string/rest_url_title" />
  <EditTextPreference
    android:key="base_url"
    android:defaultValue="@string/default_base_url"
    android:summary="@string/base_url_desc"
    android:title="@string/base_url_title" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```