# Loading Preference in Android

Tags: android, android-preferences, deprecated

From the book, Hello Android 3rd Edition. I was doing this example and I found out that one of the examples that he took, uses deprecated method.

Here it is.

```
public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
  }
}
```

The addPreferencesFromResource is deprecated. Now here are my few questions, and I'd very much appreciate pointwise answers to each if possible.

- My minimum sdk version is 10. I google something and found out that I could do it using

  ```
  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
              .replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment())
              .commit();

  public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
  }
  }
  ```

  Now this will work for all the devices with min sdk > 11, or will it work for all the devices?
- Now, in my manifest, my minSDK is 10 and the above code says that min required should be 11. So when I change it to 11, and try to run it on my Samsung galaxy ace, it does not find my phone, but when I change it back to 10, my phone becomes discoverable.
- Finally I put`@SuppressLint("NewApi")` on the top of my Prefs class definition, and within on create, I check if `Build.version.SDK_int is > 11` then do the above code, else do the previous deprecated code. Is this the right approach?

Thanks

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16374538/2556111), thanks to CommonsWare, my help.

Comment: I also check for Build version. If < 11, I use the PrefereceActivity, (yes, I had to suppress the poor Lint!) else the PreferenceFragment.