# deprecated method addPreferencesFromResources

Tags: android, methods, deprecated

I'm working with Android Studio and met a deprecated method: 
`addPreferencesFromResource` (`R.xml.settings`). 
Inizialmento I removed the deprecation and gives me the error `can not resolve symbol 'xml'`.

I wanted to know if:

- If you set the method addPreferencesFromResource again deprecated
- How can I use the method addPreferencesFromResource if it is deprecated?

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16374492/alternative-to-addpreferencesfromresource-as-its-deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a PreferenceActivity's addPreferencesFromResource, it's recommended that you use an Activity with PreferenceFragments.

PreferenceFragments also have a addPreferencesFromResource method that is not depricated.

The official documentation has a nice page describing this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html

You can also get example code by using Android Studio / Eclipse ADT's "New Activity" dialog, and then choosing a PreferenceActivity.