# "Cannot resolve method 'addPreferencesFromResource(int)'"

Tags: android, class, preferenceactivity

This is not deprecation-related. I get this error wherever I put the line `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);`, just after onCreate or in a seperate method called after.

I did include `import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;` but it shows up greyed as unused.

I'm using the latest Android Studio if it counts for something.

Comment: What's the type of the class you're trying to add this in?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what to answer. I patched up the thing mostly from [this question's 3rd answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822319/what-to-use-instead-of-addpreferencesfromresource-in-a-preferenceactivity), but I also tried to put it in my main activity's onCreate, with the same result.

Comment: I see. Post the full class code if you will.

Comment: Excuse the mess, it's a bit of a patchwork for now... Features still being implemented and everything...
http://pastebin.com/PFN320eF
Faulty one's at line 154.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compilation error occurs because you're extending [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) and not [`PreferenceActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html).

So replace

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

with

```
public class MainActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
```

and you should be good to go.

Comment: Yeah! Error's gone.
For future reference, do you think I should get this part on a seperate java activity?

Comment: I would say yes, in a different `PreferenceActivity`. I'm not sure what the best approach here is though. The link you mentioned in your comment has a lot of good advice on this manner.