# Is there an alternative for the addPrefrencesFromResources() method?

Tags: java, javascript, android, eclipse

I'm getting an Error message when using `addPrefrencesFromResources()` like this:

```
package org.example.sudoku;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity{

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);


    }

}
```

Comment: What error do you get?  Don't make people guess - that's just wasting everybody's time.  Help us to help you.

Comment: sorry buddy the addperfrencesFromResource(); method showing cross

Answer (score 0):

I suppose its not an error you are getting (red underlined) but rather a warning (yellow underlined) since **addPreferencesFromResource(...) is deprecated**?

Unfortunately there is no alternative method provided since **the preferred approach for Settings is to instantiate a PreferenceFragment**.

So you can either take the "easy way out" and ignore the warning, or use PreferenceFragment.

See here for more information:

> [What to use instead of "addPreferencesFromResource" in a PreferenceActivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822319/what-to-use-instead-of-addpreferencesfromresource-in-a-preferenceactivity)

**If you are actually getting an error message**, please make sure that you have a xml folder inside your resource folder containing "settings.xml".

Answer (score 0):

The steps to use PreferenceAcitvity as per your requirement-

1. First Create a xml folder in res folder.
2. Then create new preference xml named settings and take whatever controls you want to use in settings.
3. After that create a new Activity which extends the PrefenrenceActivity as you are creating.
4. Register your Activity in Android Manifest file.

Thats all. Now you can check where you have committed mistake.

Thanks.