# The method addPreferencesFromResource(int) from the type PreferenceActivity is deprecated

Tags: android, android-preferences

What are the other methods to replace the method

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
```

Can this will get any errors in feauture

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822319/what-to-use-instead-of-addpreferencesfromresource-in-a-preferenceactivity Hope it might help. No alternative method is provided in the method's description because the preferred approach (as of API level 11) is to instantiate PreferenceFragment objects to load your preferences from a resource file. See the sample code here: PreferenceActivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [PreferenceFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html) instead. You may face some troubles in the future, right now `PreferenceActivity` works fine.