# Write and read preferences from non default file

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferences

how can I write and read preferences to and from an non default file using androids preferences.

Following code is working but it is deprecated:

```
    public class MyPreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity 
    {
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

             PreferenceManager prefMgr = getPreferenceManager();
             prefMgr.setSharedPreferencesName("my_preferences");
             prefMgr.setSharedPreferencesMode(MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

             addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }
    }
```

In addition I need to bind the custom preference file to my Activitiy/Fragment so that any user changes in the preferences by the user are saved automatically to the custom file.

The background is following: I'm writing a widget and every instance of that widget needs its own preferences. So I need to save and load the preference for every widget seperatly.

I did not find any solution for this without using deprecated code. Any help is really welcome :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPrefernces("fileName", 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, sometimes it is so easy ;). But how do I bind non default preferences to my preferences.xml, so that the values get updated automatically?

Comment: You have to do it like i wrote first. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6822461/1965084 I didn't understand the downvote  without comment anyway...

Comment: @alex: I don't want to write to the preferences manually. I'd like to bind a none default preference file to my preferences, so that they get updated automatically if the user changes any values. The background is that I'm coding a widget. Any widget should have its own persistent preferences. By the way I did not downvote you. But I'll give you an upvote.

Comment: thanks :) have a look at the link, it explains how to bind your properties to a preferences xml automatically in a not deprecated way.

Answer (score 0):

To read and write settings on your own you can use the following code:

```
// Get preferences
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =  PreferenceManager.setSharedPreferencesName("SomeFilename",0);
PreferenceManager.setSharedPreferencesMode(MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
// Read some values
String name = sharedPreferences.getString("Key", "defaultValue");
[...]
//Write preferences
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getSharedPreferencesName("SomeFilename", 0);
// Write some values
Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("key", "someValue");
[...]
editor.commit();
```

Documentation can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html).