# Preference is not displayed correctly on Tablet

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferencefragment

I'm using a `PreferenceFragment` and load the preference from xml in the onCreate-Method of the `PreferenceFragment`:

```
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
     {
      ...
      addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences_base);
      PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getActivity(), R.xml.preferences_base, false);  
      ...
     }
```

This is an excerpt from the preference_base.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="boolStartSettings"
            android:title="@string/prefBoolStartSettings"
            android:summary="@string/prefBoolStartSettingsSummary"
            android:defaultValue="false"/>

...

</PreferenceScreen>
```

This works fine and as expected in the simulator and on my Galaxy S4. Today I tested the app on a GalaxyTab and now the preferences are not displayed correctly:

Here is a screenshot from my Galaxy S4:
[image]

and here is a screenshot from the GalaxyTab
[image]

As you can see, there is a strange frame or border in landscape-mode in the preference-view.

Any idea why that happens and how to solve this?

---

**EDIT:**

I've implemented a preferences subscreen in my preferences now and this is shown correctly:
[image]

If I press the up-Button to get to my main preferences page the strange frame/border is still there.

I'm afraid that will not help very much but here is an excerpt from my preferences xml with the subscreen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- not shown correctly -->
...    
    <PreferenceCategory
            android:title="@string/prefKatEffectsAndAnimations">
            <PreferenceScreen
                android:key="@string/keyPrefDetails"
                android:title="@string/prefCmdDetailSettings"
                android:persistent="true">
                    <!-- shown correctly -->
                    ...
            </PreferenceScreen>
    </PreferenceCategory>
...
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: Is the 'frame/border' there only when in Landscape or in portrait as well? Also, does explicitly declaring `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` on the `PreferenceScreen` make any difference?

Comment: @RudiKershaw: The problem occures only in landscape mode. I have tested `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` but it does not work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that your activity extends Activity, not PreferenceActivity.
I have the same when I use advise from here [What to use instead of "addPreferencesFromResource" in a PreferenceActivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822319/what-to-use-instead-of-addpreferencesfromresource-in-a-preferenceactivity)

Comment: I have not the slightest idea why this works but it works :)... Thanks!