# Key-Value Observing in Android

Tags: android, key-value-observing

What is the equivalent of key-value observing in Android?

Is there something like `addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:` in iphone?

Comment: What does key-value do in iphone? Are they similar to sharedpreferences?

Comment: Nope, it's a mechanism where properties of objects can be registered to listen. It's not limited to `sharedPreferences`. It's a general system for all objects. Main usage area is listening to model changes in the UI.

Comment: I dont think such a unified listener exists

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to do is detect if a shared preference has changed you might want to take a look at this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997907/android-how-to-detect-if-changes-were-made-on-the-preferences) which seems to address what you are after.

If not you might want to elaborate on exactly what you are trying to accomplish