# Reload Fragment whenever particular SharedPreference value changes

Tags: android, android-fragments, listener, sharedpreferences

I have the following layout of my fragments in the main activity:

```
 _______________ _______________ _______________
|               |               |               |
|               |               |               |
|     Left      |     Main      |     Right     |
|  SlidingMenu  |   Fragment    |  SlidingMenu  |
|               |               |               |
|               |               |               |
|_______________|_______________|_______________|
```

Many times user changes something in left or right sliding menu and then I need to reload data (in most cases `ListViews` populated from SQLite database) in Main Fragment or in Left or Right SlidingMenu. The changes I'm talking about are always saved to `SharedPreferences`.

**How do I reload data every time some particular `SharedPreferences` value changes?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set a `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` where ever you want and then in the callback just check for the key you are interested in and update the fragment when the preference is changed

Comment: Considering my layout, do I have to implement `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` in the activity that wraps all the fragments and reload all the fragments from my activity?

Comment: you can implement that in your fragment

Answer (score 0):

You should be using an OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener :) In the callback you can then perform any layout changes that you require.

You may find this question useful:

[How to detect if changes were made in the preferences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997907/android-how-to-detect-if-changes-were-made-on-the-preferences)

Comment: Considering my layout, do I have to implement `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` in the activity that wraps all the fragments and reload all the fragments from my activity?