# Can a hacker avoid detection when changing the SharedPreferences object even though I checked it?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, roles

My app is based on **different** roles. For example teacher, parent and so on. So different users will see different activites and have different permissions. And if the device is **rooted** the SharedPreferences object **could be modified.**

I save the role from the user in a SharedPreferences object when he logs in(I receive his role from a database query).

He could easily change his role to the teacher for example and have more permissions. He could delete **all the data.**

After a little research, I found this: [How to detect if changes were made in the preferences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997907/how-to-detect-if-changes-were-made-in-the-preferences)

My question now is: Could a hacker avoid detection when changing the values from the object even though I checked it like in the example above?

Comment: `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` wouldn't even work because a hacker would change the file directly outside the context of the app.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  If you want security, check the permissions on the server every time you make a request, and don't send down anything he shouldn't be able to see.  Then the best he can do is get some extra buttons that throw an error when pressed.

Comment: But then I need to know his username in order to provide him his permissions/activities(I need this for a query). How would you store this information?

Comment: Look into token based authentication.  You don't need to send the username/password with each request.