# how to turn on SwitchPreference programatically on Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, android-settings

I've a settings fragment which load a xml with a default settings page, I also added one click listener to one specific preference

```
   @Override
        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Load the preferences from an XML resource
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
       preferences.findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_custom_list)).setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
//other stuff.....
```

this works fine, when user clicks triggers an event and i can check some info about the switch including deny the change...

But i would like to turn on/off other switches in the same screen when this even happen

i tried to

```
   preferences.findPreference(getString(R.string.xpto)).setEnabled(true);
```

but it doesn't turn any switch on or off... it just set the view enabled or disabled for clicks

if i do something like
`PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putBoolean("xpto",true).apply();`

It does change the preference, but the changes are not loaded to the screen so user doesn't know

how can i switch some preference on or off programatically and make it reflect to the preference screen

Answer (score 3):

You can use `SwitchPreferenceCompat`.

```
<SwitchPreferenceCompat
    app:key="key"
    app:title="Some Confs" />
```

Try this in your fragment if you are using `SwitchPreferenceCompat` as above.

```
SwitchPreferenceCompat switchPref = findPreference("key");
switchPref.setChecked(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `setChecked()`, not `setEnabled()`:

```
preferences.findPreference(getString(R.string.xpto)).setChecked(true);
```

Comment: there is not set checked method, in the preference class

Comment: @abinav chauhan . cast the preference into switchpreference then you will get setchecked property

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement a listener when the `SharedPreferences` change.

```
SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener spChanged = new
                       SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
        String key) {
    // change the Switch Preference state here
    }
};
```

Then when the prefs change, you can change the user's screen to match it.

For your reference:

[How to detect if changes were made in the preferences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997907/how-to-detect-if-changes-were-made-in-the-preferences)

Comment: i wasn't clear in my question, i do get the events properly... what i dont know is how to turn on OTHER preferences besides the one clicked