# View an Android App's shared preferences?

Tags: android, debugging, sdk, sharedpreferences, preferences

When I am working on my app in eclipse, is there a way to see the changes I make to the shared preferences of the app while it is debugging in the emulator? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Run project in emulator, then from Eclipse choose menu Windows-> open perspective ->DDMS. 
From tab device, choose emulator name, then go to file explorer,expand data->data->yourpackagename, you should see share reference xml file (*only work on the emulator or a rooted device*). Finally, export this file to windows. 
See http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html

**Update**:
Another way, you can listen shared preference change:

```
SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener prefListener = 
new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
  public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs,String key) {
if (key.equals("YourKey")) 
     {
          //Get this
     } 
 }

SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);          
preferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(prefListener);
```

See [SharedPreferences.onSharedPreferenceChangeListener not being called consistently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542938/sharedpreferences-onsharedpreferencechangelistener-not-being-called-consistently)

Comment: Yes, but that method will only work on the emulator or a device where adb runs as root; otherwise you will need to use the run-as tool or have the app itself export the data.

Comment: I know, I recommend this way because taormania want to see in his emulator.

Comment: To easily export the file from the DDMS perspective, just click on the "pull" button--it looks like a floppy disk with a red arrow pointing left into it.

Comment: Is it possible to view an apps shared preferences that is live in production? (I hope not)

Comment: @MicroR the answer is yes if device is rooted (because users have fully permission on rooted device, especially access the system files). If you want the security, you can try this https://github.com/scottyab/secure-preferences . This lib helps to encrypt the data save in SharedPreference

Answer (score 3):

Running on emulator --> Go to file explorer --> data/data/yourapplication's package/Sharedpreferences.xml can be seen

Comment: The device needs to be rooted for this method.

Comment: Not really, some application can allow its data to be extracted, if allowBackUp set to false in androidmanifest.xml file.

Comment: with help of adb backup command, one can extract data of appllication.