# My Android application does not store the high score

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm developing a simple game in Android and even i followed the steps found in the net, the highscore of my app is never saved. I'm using SharedPreferences to store, but I'm quietly sure the problem is in there, because I don't understand at all how to use it.Hope you guys can help me, thanks.

```
    package com.example.memory;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

public class Final extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    TextView levelReachedText;
    TextView bestScoreText;
    int levelReached, bestScore;    
    Intent intent;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.finals);
        levelReachedText = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.nivel);
        bestScoreText = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.best);
        Button menu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.inicio);
        menu.setOnClickListener(this);
        intent = getIntent();
        levelReached = intent.getIntExtra("nivel", 1);
        SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("bestScore", MODE_PRIVATE);
        int savedScore = preferences.getInt("selectedScore", 0);

        levelReachedText.setText("You reached level "+levelReached );
        if(savedScore>levelReached){
            bestScore = savedScore;
        }else{
            bestScore = levelReached;
        }
        bestScoreText.setText("Maximum level reached "+levelReached);


}
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.inicio:
                SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("mejorScore", MODE_PRIVATE);
                preferences.edit().putInt("selectedScore", bestScore).commit();
                this.finish();
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You are storing the high score in the SharedPreferences called "mejorScore" and then trying to load it from the SharedPreferences called "bestScore". That looks like a problem

Comment: @Borre just changed it, still getting the same problem, no save

Answer (score 3):

you are saving score value in `mejorScore` and trying to get it from `bestScore`.So either change

```
SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("mejorScore", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to

```
SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("bestScore", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

or vice-versa.

Comment: just changed it, still getting the same problem, no save

Comment: @yep cleat your project and retry.see [View an Android App's shared preferences?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354904/view-an-android-apps-shared-preferences) to view your shared preference file