# Android registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() not working

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I've got a really weird one. I have 2 apps, a free app and a paid app, both using basically the same code, with the exception of some code to show ads in the free one.

For some reason, registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() doesn't run in the free version. What's even weirder... if I put a breakpoint at that line of code, and run the debugger, it registers fine. Without the breakpoint there, it never registers. Any idea what would cause this? Maybe something that differs in the project settings? I've been trying to fix this all day!

code:

```
SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener prefsListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
            if(key.equals(AUTORESPONSEGLOBAL))
            {
                ARCheckBox.setChecked(settings.getBoolean(AUTORESPONSEGLOBAL, false));
                if(ARCheckBox.isChecked())
                {
                    //green 0xaarrggbb a=alpha
                    AR_label.setTextColor(0xff00ff00);
                }
                else
                {
                    //red
                    AR_label.setTextColor(0xffff0000);
                }
            }
            if(key.equals(CLOCK24))
            {
                updateTime();
            }
        }
    };

    settings.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(prefsListener);
```

Comment: This is really hard to answer, as you've not given much to work with. Can you explain the context of this code (where does it exist), who is updating a preference and when? By what method are you determining that the function never gets called? Do you have a log statement, or are you expecting some other side effect of calling the function?

Comment: I ran the code with a break point in the method, and it never got to the break point. When I put a break point at the register line, it then got into to the method. The preference is being changed when a checkbox is clicked by the user. I've looked through the logcat and there is nothing in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I'm still not sure why it was working in one project and not the other... but I fixed it.

I was declaring `SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener prefsListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() { ... };` in `onCreate()`. I changed it to it's own separate method, and it seems to work fine now. I changed both projects to work this way, to keep things consistent.

Comment: The reason is that you cannot use an anonymous inner class as a listener. I also experienced this problem.
See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542938/sharedpreferences-onsharedpreferencechangelistener-not-being-called-consistently