# sharedpreferences does not update

Tags: android

I've a code to change a duration of animation, at first start of program "preferenze" runs to read sharedpreferences, later, users can change duration of animation by Preferences.class. Seems ok but I can't update preferences, my code:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ 
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

// runs every time app starts

```
preferenze();
```

// read shared
    private void preferenze() {

```
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        CheckboxPreference = prefs.getBoolean("checkboxPref", true);
        String ListPreference = prefs.getString("listpref", "1500");


public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

menu.add("Impostazioni").setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Vai al Racconto... Non attivo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //goToPage();
                Intent settingsActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                        Preferences.class);
        startActivity(settingsActivity);

public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs,
            String listpref) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "eseguo changed: "+listpref, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          if (fade == 500){
            animazione = R.style.MyCustomTheme1;
        }
        else if (fade == 1000){
            animazione = R.style.MyCustomTheme2;
        }
        else if (fade == 1500){
            animazione = R.style.MyCustomTheme3;
        }
        else if (fade == 2000){
            animazione = R.style.MyCustomTheme4;
        }

    }
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Comment: It would be more easier to guess what's wrong if you can explain a bit more. If you encounter any kind of error, please post error with logcat. But my wild guess would be that you forget to `commit()` your `SharedPreference Editor`

Comment: Are you sure that `onSharedPreferenceChanged` is called? (Can you see the Toast?). If yes, I think you forget to commit your edited changes to your properties file. Am I right?

Comment: @yougidroid: no... no toast showes and I don't understand.

Comment: @HERO: no errors: but when I change (using preferences) the value of duration, old value is always stored.

Comment: @PolHallen, Than means your didn't commited you changes. Take a look at my answer bellow please.

Answer (score 0):

If your `onSharedPreferenceChanged` is being called then you forget to commit your edited changes to your properties file.
Try to replace you method with the following one:

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs,
            String listpref) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "eseguo changed: "+listpref, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          if (fade == 500){
            animazione = R.style.MyCustomTheme1;
        }
        else if (fade == 1000){
            animazione = R.style.MyCustomTheme2;
        }
        else if (fade == 1500){
            animazione = R.style.MyCustomTheme3;
        }
        else if (fade == 2000){
            animazione = R.style.MyCustomTheme4;
        }

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("listpref", fade);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

IDK if this your point, but you should follow the kind of ideia. After the change always commit edited values. Let me know if it works.

Comment: This might be irrelevant question but How costly is it to retrieve/update shared preferences data? Does the whole process take more than 16 milli seconds (from real time games' perspective)?

Comment: I've never thought about it before but it is suposed to be a fast process. Why do you ask?

Comment: @yugidroid For my upcoming game.. being a noob coder, I am using sharedPreferences editor for every 1 second.. anyway.. thanx

Comment: What's the target API of your app? Take a look in http://stackoverflow.com/a/3104265/828728 to see if it works.

Comment: Api 17. Changed value by preferences, when I restart app the value is correct. The problem in within app.