# Pass reference of one Activity to another Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, preference

I know that I can pass some values between Activities using intent. 
However, if I want to pass whole Activity to another Activity I think it is not good approach. 
Is there another way to do that?

I have Settings Activity in which I am changing some Colors. So after I come back to my Main Activity I would like to apply those colors. To do this, I need access to MainActivity fields after I change Color value, so inside PreferenceActivity. In other words, I want to have access to Main activity fields from PreferenceActivity class. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using a `SharedPreference` and then accessing that in your main activity. I recommend you reading up at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html because it seems like you are implementing your settings activity incorrectly. The part you might be specifically interested in is the **"Read Preferences"** section. However, I strongly suggest you read through the whole thing and then implement your settings the proper way.

***Updated answer with the 3 different ways (that I can think of):***

1) Start your preference activity using `startActivityForResult()`, then in your `onActivityResult()` access the `SharedPreference` and make your necessary changes. **See** [**here**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities)

2) Register a `SharedPreferenceChangeListener` with your MainActivity, which will be called when any changes happen to your `SharedPreference`. **See** [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542938/sharedpreferences-onsharedpreferencechangelistener-not-being-called-consistently/3104265#3104265) **for a detailed discussion.** Also see my initial response.

3) In your MainActivity's `onResume()`, access the `SharedPreference` and then make your changes there. I do not like this method because you will be cluttering `onResume()` with more logic and you will also probably have to have a variable that keeps track of the state of the variable you are interested in.

**I would personally go with option 2 because the callback was created for this exact purpose.**

Comment: I already read it, but I want changes to take effect straight away after coming back from PreferenceActivity

Answer (score 0):

I think you could pass the value by using method putExtra(name, value).
And after you start new activity you can get the value you pass before by using method getStringExtra(name).

Comment: @Marek : **"I want to pass whole Activity..."** - No, don't attempt to do this. Save the changes to the preferences and in the `MainActivity` simply reload the changes in `onResume()`. Either that or use `startActivityForResult(...)` which allows you to pass data back to a calling `Activity` in a `Bundle`.

Comment: @Squonk I did what you suggested. Indeed I just realized that passing whole activity is a bad idea. However, do you think that in some case it could be better? For example if I would like to change a lot of data? Please put your comment as an answer, it satisfies me the most so I would like to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Shared preferences can be used. If you want your changes to be reflected right away add listener. Refer to SharedPreferences.onSharedPreferenceChangeListener. Its an easy way to do.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to lots of changes required in many activity from you change in any one.

And access last modify data from all Activity and modify also.

for example.

**Constants.java**

```
public class Constants
{

    public static String name;
}
```

In your **MainActivity** you have an **editText**.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText yourName;
    private Button btn;

     @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    yourName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourName);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {       
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            Constants.name = yourname.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Activity2.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

}
```

In your **Activity2** you have an **TextView** and that getting value which you enter in **MainActivity.java** without pass in Intent.

**Activity2.java**

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity {

    private TextView yourName;

     @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    yourName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_yourName);

    // directly use ferom serializable class
    yourname.setText(Constants.name);
}
```

like that you use many values from all activity and modify from all activity.

Comment: I think in the example that you presented Constants class does not need to be Serializable.

Comment: Ya... for just use values from Activities it not need to Serializable... but it works easy compare to another way...