# registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener Stops getting called after some time

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-activity, android-event

I have a sharedPreference that that gets updated continuously (around every second)from a Class which extends BroadcastReceiver.

The first few times, the registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener gets called, but after a while, it stops getting called(I dont even press any button on my emulator).

I know that the sharedPreference is still getting updated because I have seen my log. It is a problem with the registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.

This is the code for the listener(using the suggestion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3104265/2670775))

My shared preference is getting updated almost once every second.

Here is the code for my listener:

```
SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener=new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
                                              String key) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(key=="TIME")
            {
                Log.v("Tagger","Value has changed");
                long L=-2;
                if(sharedPreferences.contains("TIME"))
                {
                    L=sharedPreferences.getLong("TIME", 0);

                    long  HH=(L/1000)/3600; 
                    long MM=((L/1000)/60)%60;
                    long SS=(L/1000)%60;
                    MILLIS-=1000;
                    mainHH.setText(Long.toString(HH));
                    mainMM.setText(Long.toString(MM));
                    mainSS.setText(Long.toString(SS));
                }

                if(L<=0)
                {
                    Editor edit=sharedPreferences.edit();
                    edit.remove("TIME");
                    edit.commit();

                    Log.v("VALUE",Long.toString(454L));
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TimerAlarmReceiver.class);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
                    TimerAlarmReceiver.alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                    TimerAlarmReceiver.alarmMgr.cancel(pendingIntent);
                    start.setText("Start the Test?");
                    TimerOn=false;

                    edit.putBoolean("TimerOn", TimerOn);
                    edit.commit();
                }
            }
        }};
        sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
```

I have provided the full code because something else might be the problem.

EDIT::
here is my BroadcastReceiver class

```
public class TimerAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { 
    public static long TIME;
    public static Boolean TimerOn=false;
    public static AlarmManager alarmMgr ;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

      //Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm went off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  

      /*  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putLong(key, value);
        editor.commit();*/

        SharedPreferences time = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        long T = time.getLong("TIME",594554L);

        Editor editor=time.edit();
        editor.putLong("TIME", T-1000);
        editor.commit();

        Log.v("Tag", Long.toString(T));
       //this gets updated and i can see the new values of T
    }

    public static void setTime(long T)
    {
        TIME=TimerActivity.DMILLIS;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you are saying that your Log.x get printed, but your UI components don't get updated?  And that is why you know that the listener is firing?

Comment: no, I have not posted my broadcastreceiver class. 
The log prints from there. Please see my edit

Comment: Well, key == "TIME" really should be key.equals("TIME") so that you are doing a character per character comparison instead of address space for a string.

Comment: okay, but why does it work for a few seconds in the first place?. I changed it to key.equals, it still stops

Comment: commit returns a boolean, perhaps a check to see if it stops committing at some point might be helpful.

Comment: that is only if L<0; 
L is a long int

Comment: I had meant within your onReceive()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`s are registered via weak reference. Make sure you keep a reference to the listener by setting it to an instance variable.