# Data in EditText in PreferenceActivity Android

Tags: android

In my application i am using Preference to get the data.

**My code is:**

```
SharedPreferences sp=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        sp.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(new OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences arg0, String arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Settings changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

But the Toast is not Showing when the data is changed in Preference. I am using EditText to get data.

Thanks...!

Comment: Show the code where you change the data. Maybe you forgot `commit()` or `apply()`?

Comment: @stealthjong i am not changing in preference. I want to get the data when changed in the Preference Settings Activity . In the XML there are EditTextPrefernce boxes. I want to manipulate this.

Comment: Please see this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542938/sharedpreferences-onsharedpreferencechangelistener-not-being-called-consistently/3104265#3104265. In Short: When you use the listener as an anonymous inner class it gets a target of the garbage collection as soon as it leaves the current scrope