# How to fix "actual argument <anonymous OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener> cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion"

Tags: java, android

I have the following code derived from `Service` which I want to run as a service, in the background. In this class, I use a `SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` class to check if a shared preference has change, in order to reinitialize a `BroadcastReceiver` to be run at some defined time intervals (like every 6 hours). But when I change the explicit shared preference in my main activity to 3 hours, for example, I need the code to be run in 3 hours (instead of 6 hours). Here is the code for the `Service`:

```
public class AlarmService extends Service
{
    public Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
    public SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener spChanged = new
            SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
                                                      String key) {                       
                    // reinitialize the alarm
                    alarm.SetAlarm(this); // ERROR HERE
                }
        };
        //SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        sharedPref.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(spChanged);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        Log.d("!~!", "Service started.");
        alarm.SetAlarm(this);
        return START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The method `SetAlarm` is defined in a class derived from `BroadcastReceiver` and is implemented as follows:

```
 public void SetAlarm(Context context)
    {
        // get the update cylce from the prefences
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        int updateInterval = Integer.parseInt(sharedPref.getString("updateInterval", "24"));
        Log.d(LOGHEAD, String.format("Alarm set to update every %d hours.", updateInterval));


        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * updateInterval, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
    }
```

But when I compile the code, I get the following error:

```
Error:(33, 26) error: method SetAlarm in class Alarm cannot be applied to given types;
required: Context
found: <anonymous OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener>
reason: actual argument <anonymous OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener> cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion
```

The place at the error's occurrence is marked above. Once more I get an error related to the 'context', a concept, I am still failing to understand...

I am especially puzzled by the fact, that futher below on the code the call

```
alarm.SetAlarm(this);
```

is working fine. Maybe the issue is because of the use of an inner class?

Any ideas how to fix this? Or fix the whole code? I have put together the code from examples and I am not sure if this is good android code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that particular context `this` does refer to the `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` as shown in the error message.

Replace `this` with `AlarmService.this` to reference the outer service instance and things should work.

Based on you comment you also need to initialize the preferences inside of `onCreate()`.

First only declare the preferences

```
private SharedPreferences sharedPref;
```

and then inside `onCreate()` do

```
sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Comment: Updated the answer to address your other issue too.

Comment: I see. Also something to be aware of that you might run into is the behavior described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3104265/1435985) about registering a `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` without keeping a strong reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a listener `this` refers to the `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` object which does not extend the `Context` class. You need to pass a valid `Context` object to your `setAlarm` method.
However when you call setAlarm in the onStartCommand, `this` represents your AlarmService object.

For further reference - read the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)