# Shared Preferences updated value not reflected in Service

Tags: android, service, sharedpreferences

My application is calling a service at app launch.

In the app, I am updating the value of a given key-value pair

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.shared_preferences_name), MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("key",value);
    editor.apply();
```

and I'm trying to fetch it from the service

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.shared_preferences_name), MODE_PRIVATE);
String key = preferences.getString("key",null);
```

but the service always displays the old key value. i.e, the value is reflected only after an app launch or service restart.

How to fetch the updated value in the service without restarting the service or the app?

As mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener)) Shared Preferences don't work across multiple processes. Any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener))

`Note: This class does not support use across multiple processes.`

So it wouldn't reflect changes instantaneously.

Answer (score 0):

You need `OnSharedPeferencesChangeListener` to listen for updates of preferences.
Reason it's displaying old value is because it's not updated(Lines of the codes are not called). You need to trigger event to update it.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = 
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(
new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(
        SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {

        String key = prefs.getString("key",null);
    }
});`
```

**EDIT:** You need strong reference for `SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` object. Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542938/sharedpreferences-onsharedpreferencechangelistener-not-being-called-consistently)

Comment: Doesn't call the listener on any occasion.

Comment: change this line then. `SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.shared_preferences_name), MODE_PRIVATE);`

Comment: Tried that also. Still doesn't call.

Comment: SharedPreferences don't work across multiple processes. Any alternative?

Comment: `You must store a strong reference to the listener, or it will be susceptible to garbage collection.`. That's solution!

Comment: Did that too. Didn't work. I am now forced to use DB. Could you suggest any better alternative?

Answer (score 0):

you must add

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
super.onResume();
```

for updating reading instantly, commit(); or apply (); may not work for some cases, this method definitely will work.

**below is our Example**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wi_fi);}       
     @Override
     public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences mPreferences = 
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPreferences.edit();

    String name = mPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.name), "");
    
    editTextAddress.setText(name);
    button1.setText(name);
}
```

if any doubts ping me