# AsyncTask best practice: update and filter activity and widget ListView on fcm

Tags: android

actually I'm working on a android app where Activity and Widget ListView is populated via AsyncTask.  Here is my current implementation

AsyncTask-
     AsyncTask fetch json from url (if internet available else read from the assets Jason file) and populate ListView via ArrayAdapter with model.

MainActivity-
     AsyncTask is executed from the onCreate method of MainActivity

WIDGET-
     WidgetProvider also use this AsyncTask class to populate ListView.

FCMMESSAGINGSERVICE-
     It will send intents to the MainActivity and MainActivity will handle this intent and execute the AsyncTask again.

Everything is working fine and perfect according to the requirement. But I want to know that can this scenario will be achieved via much better way...

Like: 
     On fcm notification, some kind of datachanged method will directly populate the updated/modified ListView for MainActivity as well as for WidgetProvider.

Here one more thing I want to know that, this ListView has some filters that can be changed via SettingsActivity. Currently user have relaunch the app to re-execute the AsyncTask after filter changed. I don't know how to directly  manipulate the ListView, if settings is updated.

Thanks & regards

Answer (score 0):

Personally I don't think your approach is incorrect.

There is one change that I think is necessary for you: instead of starting the `MainActivity` from the `FcmMessagingService`, create a notification that, when clicked, starts the `MainActivity`. It will be way nicer to your users, instead of starting an activity out of nowhere.

About the Settings updates, you need to implement a listener for when the preference value changes. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542938/sharedpreferences-onsharedpreferencechangelistener-not-being-called-consistently) has a good example:

```
// Use instance field for listener
// It will not be gc'd as long as this instance is kept referenced
listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
  public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
    // Implementation
  }
};

prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
```

Comment: Thanks @BMacedo for your valuable time and suggestion regarding fcm. Personally I also thinks that this approach is ok, but seeking for some good approaches. Let me check some other options (answers and comments) before marking your answer as correct.