# Android Studio OnSharedPreferenceChangedListener not working in MainActivity

Tags: android-studio, listener

I have a daily alarm and a settings page that allow users to change the timing that the daily alarm fires. I have a OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener in my SettingsFragment that extends PreferenceFragmentCompat and it is working here. However, when I do the same thing in my MainActivity, it does not seem to be working.

This is my code in Main Activity:
'''

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//some other variables
private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener preferenceChangeListener;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//some other code

preferenceChangeListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
                if (key.equals("daily alarm time")){
                    int alarmTime = sharedPreferences.getInt("daily alarm time", 36000000);
                    setdailyalarm(alarmTime, true, false);
                    System.out.println("onsharedpreferencechange activited");
                }
                if (key.equals("daily alarm toggle")){
                    Boolean dailyAlarmToggle = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, true);
                    System.out.println("111111111111111111111111");
                    if (dailyAlarmToggle){
                        int alarmTime = sharedPreferences.getInt(key, 36000000);
                        setdailyalarm(alarmTime, true, false);
                    }
                    else{
                        int alarmTime = sharedPreferences.getInt(key, 36000000);
                        setdailyalarm(alarmTime, true, true);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

}
```

'''

This is my onpause and onresume:
'''

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(preferenceChangeListener);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(preferenceChangeListener);

    }
```

'''

When I start my app and check my System.out, '''System.out.println("onsharedpreferencechange activited");''' does not seem to be firing which means my OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener is not working.  I have seem the other discussions [SharedPreferences.onSharedPreferenceChangeListener not being called consistently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542938/sharedpreferences-onsharedpreferencechangelistener-not-being-called-consistently) but it does not seem to be the solution to my problem.

Comment: have you try only registering the listener in `onCreate()` and commenting the unregister part?

Comment: OMG it works. I am such a fool. It is unregistered every time I change my sharedpreferences since I will be in the Settings activity. Thank you so much xDD Do you know if I dun unregister it, does it affect performance in any way?

Comment: Great that it works! If you didn't unregister the listener, it will keep listening to the changes. I usually unregister it in `onDestroy` on whenever I call `finish()`. Let me create an answer to close the question then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I start my app and check my System.out, '''System.out.println("onsharedpreferencechange activited");''' does not seem to be firing which means my OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener is not working.

It's because you're always unregistering the listener in your `onPause()`. So, whenever you leave the activity, the listener is removed and you can't listen for the `SharedPreferences` changes.

You could register the listener inside your `onCreate()` method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // setup the listener
    preferenceChangeListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
    ...

    // then register it
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(preferenceChangeListener);

}
```

Then unregister the listener when you close the activity by overriding the `onDestroy()` method:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(preferenceChangeListener);

  super.onDestroy();
}
```

Or unregister the listener whenever you call `finish()` method. Either call the unregister part before `finish()` or overriding the `finish()` method.