# How to reflect in the screen the state of a specific item of SharedPreferences changed programmatically?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am implementing code whereby the user can uncheck an option in the Preferences.

If that happens, I launch a dialog with a message to the user. If the user clicks on `Confirm` the preference would remain with that changed value and the App would close. That works fine.

But if the user clicks `Cancel`, I revert the value of the preference back to `true` programmatically, but the change is not reflected on the screen (the option appears as disabled).

My question is: is there a way to **visibly** update that item, so that it fires when the user clicks `Cancel` (since the value of the item will return to `true` in that case)?

Or, is there a way to undo the last change to the SharedPreferences and have this reflected immediately in the GUI?

This is my code:

#### Fragment

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general, rootKey);
        Preference acceptTerms = findPreference(PREF_ACCEPT);

        acceptTerms.setOnPreferenceClickListener(
                arg0 -> {
                    showConfirm();
                    return true;
                });
    }

    private void showConfirm() {
        MaterialAlertDialogBuilder materialAlertDialogBuilder = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(getActivity());
        materialAlertDialogBuilder.setTitle(DIALOG_LEGAL_TITLE);
        materialAlertDialogBuilder.setMessage(DIALOG_LEGAL_BODY);
        materialAlertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(DIALOG_LEGAL_OK,
                (dialogInterface, i) -> closeApp());
        materialAlertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(DIALOG_LEGAL_CANCEL,
                (dialogInterface, i) -> updatePreference());
        materialAlertDialogBuilder.show();
    }

    private void closeApp() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).finishAffinity();
        } else {
            Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).finishAndRemoveTask();
        }
    }

    /*
       Here the preference is set to true internally 
       but not changed in the GUI. 
       My idea is to find a way to make it activate in the GUI
    */
    private void updatePreference(){
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(PREF_ACCEPT, true);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

#### XML

```
    <SwitchPreference
        android:key="accept_terms"
        android:title="@string/pref_accept_terms"
        android:summary="@string/pref_description_accept_terms"
        android:defaultValue="false"
        />
```

Comment: Still in Java? Please, subscribe to SharedPreferences, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542938/sharedpreferences-onsharedpreferencechangelistener-not-being-called-consistently, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener. Probably you don't need SP to reflect changes.

Comment: Add logic when calling the updatePreference method that changes the UI accordingly to what you want. Since this is a small snippet of your application and I don't know where exactly is the place that you display the change, you can use [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata).